# How to show onbeforeload window for iframe?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I have a flash game from another website iframed on my site. 
I want to prevent users for leaving my site when clicking a banner inside the flash game that redirect to another website.

I tried the sanbox thing but didnt work.

is this possible since the iframed content is a flash game?

Comment: Users don't like being prevented from leaving a website. That being said, is the iframe hosted cross domain?

Comment: yes is cross domain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the iframe is cross domain there isn't really anything you can do unless you have access to that server. Check out [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS)(Cross Origin Resource Sharing), but I think even that will only get you as far as XHR requests go. It still wouldn't allow your scripts to access the contents of the iframe unless it is hosted on the same domain.